# sum inside list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list comprehension operation like below:

```
a = [1,2,15]
def tt(n):
 if n < 1:
  return [[]]
 st= tt(n-1)
 return [row + [v*a[n-1]] for row  in st for v in [0,1]]

tt(3)
```

I am trying to get sum of each sub list rather than the list.

I currently get :

```
[[0, 0, 0],  
[0, 0, 15],  
[0, 2, 0],  
[0, 2, 15],  
[1, 0, 0],  
[1, 0, 15],  
[1, 2, 0],  
[1, 2, 15]]
```

I tried:

```
a = [1,2,15]
def tt(n):
 if n < 1:
  return [[]]
 st= tt(n-1)
 return [row + [sum([v*a[n-1]])] for row  in st for v in [0,1]]

tt(3)
```

Expected:
`[0,15,2,17,1,3,18]`

My final aim is to run tt(40) or above.

Comment: Yes, the easiest way is to crunch the result of your existing recursive function after it's done. But if you want to modify your function to directly return your desired result, it only needs a few modifications.

Comment: I will have to go this to level of 40 to 50 which makes it difficult to get the list and then sum it later… running tt(40) and getting sum might be more difficult

Comment: I can imagine (2^40 is kinda huge :) ); then look at my modified version of your func.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a modified version of your code (but Daniel Hao's suggestion remains valid).

```
a = [1,2,15]
def tt(n):
 if n < 1:
  return [0]
 st= tt(n-1)
 return [row + v*a[n-1] for row  in st for v in [0,1]]
```

Comment: I am getting error saying int cannot be added to list

Comment: Did you replace return [[]] with return[0] as I did ?

Comment: It worked.. thanks… is there anyway i can get only sum >0 ratger than everything

Comment: you can filter the end result with: result = [i for i in result if i]. That said, it will only be useful if there are zeroes or negative values in a, else only the 1st element of the result is 0.

Comment: Oh, I just realized what your function does :) (all the sums of subsets of a if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: You gave the right answer… but scaling to a level of 40 causes problems…

Comment: Just tested it; indeed at best it's very slow (if it doesn't crash); not that surprising since it should return 2^40 (so about 10^12) values.